# summing up rows in c showing garbage numbers in columns

Tags: c, arrays, sum, row

I'm trying to sum columns in C. My code only adds the sum for the firsts columns for example if is a 2x2 array it only add the first column but for the rest it displays weird numbers. this is what i got so far. I haven't made the code for the rows yet. Thanks for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){


printf("Enter the number of columns");
int i;
scanf("%d", &i);
printf("Enter the number of rows");
int y;
scanf("%d", &y);

int r[i][y];
int a;
int b;
int columntotal[i],rowtotal[y];

for (a=0; a<i; a++){
   for (b=0; b<y; b++){
     scanf("%d",&r[a][b]);
   }
}


//printing
for(a=0;a<i;a++)
{
   for(b=0;b<y;b++){

      printf("\t%d", r[a][b]);

   }
printf("\n");
}




for (a=0;a<i;a++){
  for (b=0;b<y;b++){
      columntotal[a]=columntotal[a]+r[a][b];

  }
}
for (a=0;a<i;a++){
    printf("%d\n", columntotal[a]);
}

return(0);
}
```

Comment: C arrays are normally arranged as `array[rows][cols]`. And you need to initialize the `columntotal` array before using it. When you declare a variable (array or otherwise) inside a function, the starting value of that variable is indeterminate until you assign a value to it.

Comment: `int columntotal[i];` --> `int columntotal[i] = { 0 };`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember dynamic rows,col assign while creating array is not possible in C.So your this statement `int columntotal[i],rowtotal[y];` will not work unless i,y is a constant variable i.e `#define i,y,etc` which is not in your case.

Second you are iterating over a `columntotal` array which is not properly declared. You can make use of dynamic memory allocation to allocate number of blocks to `columntotal array` and then fill it with you column sum as you iterate over it.

```
int *columntotal= malloc(i * sizeof (int));
for (a=0;a<i;a++){
  for (b=0;b<y;b++){
    columntotal[a]=columntotal[a]+r[a][b];   //r is your 2D array

  }
}
```